When is a Zero rolled?
The spinners in Dokapon Kingdom go from 0 to 6, but you very rarely roll a Zero, for many it's only a few times in a playthrough full of hundreds of turns. I want to know the details  of when exactly a Zero is rolled. Is it just a random chance, if yes than what is the probabability of it? I have also heard online that AI Players seem to roll Zeros way more often, some people claiming they had an AI roll a Zero 4 times in a row. Is that true? Why is that the case, is that just some form of AI cheating or is there more to it?
I had a theory that a Zero is rolled everytime the number you would have rolled (which is predetermined before you even roll) wouldn't get you to any spaces you could land on. But I have now disproven this theory. In this video clip the Blue Player is boxed in by Roadbloack Rocks on both sides, making so that a Zero is the only valid roll he could get, but the game still let's him roll a 3, which results in him doing nothing on his turn. So that is not what a Zero means.
One more thing to consider: Through the use of Spinner items the player can get more than just one spinner at a time. Does the chance of rolling a Zero change when the player has multiple spinners? I could imagine that, because getting a Zero on one of those spinners wouldn't make the result a Zero, like it would with only one spinner.
